# A single object appears black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a simple face object. And when rendered it appears black. Textures work in view port textured mode. I've tried recalculating normals. I'm Using Cycles. Uv map is turned on.
[image: Viewport]
[image: Object panel]

Comment: does it accept light? Maybe show us your node set up of your face material and the world settings please

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. http://i.imgur.com/J2XO8jF.png. I think theres something wrong with the data. Heres the .blend http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the custom normals you have on your mask and horns objects.

Before clearing custom split normals:
[image]

After (using a simple diffuse shader I created while debugging the file):
[image]

Comment: Oh wow. Was so simple in the end. Thank you very much!