# What causes shading artifacts and how to eliminate them?

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface

I've been getting these shading inconsistencies with sub surf mod regardless of the subdivisions value, and "Smooth Vertex" deforms my shape undesirably. how do I go about fixing this? 
[image: Shading Artifacts]

This is how it looks in Edit mode:
[image: Edit mode]

Comment: Seems like a problem with your topology. Can you add more pictures in EDIT mode? or even better, a .blend file?

Comment: @CosDim I edited the question

Comment: Most likely either [wrong normals orientation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) or [custom split normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40475/a-single-object-appears-black).

Comment: @MrZak I checked the normals they're good - I'm going to check your second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your topology is the culprit. Subdivison modifier tends to not work well with triangles like the ones you have. Try using only quads (squares). 
Other than that, I think your normals are flipped. Try this: Hit "T" to bring up the left hand panel on the viewport. Then go into EDIT mode and find the "Shading/UVs" tab. There scroll down and click "Flip Direction".
Hope this helps.

Comment: The topology was the problem indeed - using quads only seemed to fix the problem quite nicely